# How to purge Data from already truncated Mysql 5.6 partitions?

Tags: mysql, partitioning, database-partitioning, mysql-5.6

I have a table that is being written to by different applications. To keep a check on number of rows in this table, I had implemented a partitioning scheme based on DAY_OF_YEAR, yielding 52 partitions, one for each week of the year. The scheduled job to truncate older partitions runs weekly.

After the past run, p27, p28 and p29 have had all the rows in them purged. However, when I tried to view information corresponding to the row counts of the partitions using the following query:

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.partitions where table_schema = 'myDB';
```

I got the following result:

```
TABLE_NAME          PARTITION_NAME      PARTITION_ORDINAL_POSITION  PARTITION_METHOD    PARTITION_EXPRESSION    PARTITION_DESCRIPTION   TABLE_ROWS  AVG_ROW_LENGTH  DATA_LENGTH     INDEX_LENGTH    DATA_FREE   
outbound_messages   p27                 27                          RANGE               DAYOFYEAR(created_at)   190                     0           0               4574101504      2393751552      7194279936  
outbound_messages   p28                 28                          RANGE               DAYOFYEAR(created_at)   197                     0           0               3436199936      3680010240      14167310336 
outbound_messages   p29                 29                          RANGE               DAYOFYEAR(created_at)   204                     0           0               509624320       6084018176      45427458048 
outbound_messages   p30                 30                          RANGE               DAYOFYEAR(created_at)   211                     36995867    1713            63385387008     29497769984     7340032
```

Despite the row count being zero in p27, p28 and p29, the 'data_length' parameter is non-zero. In order to see how much these rowless partitions contribute to the size of data in the whole table, I ran the below query to get size contribution in MB:

```
select ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1) from information_schema.partitions where table_schema = 'myDB' and (partition_name = 'p27' or partition_name = 'p28' or partition_name = 'p29')
```

which yielded 19719.8 MB as the result.

Why does this happen?
How do i purge all data from the partitions?

Comment: Are you using innodb_file_per_table ? If so, you can check the actual files.

Answer (score 0):

There are about 365 days in a year, not 52.  So I am confused by how you are partitioning.  It would be better to show use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, including at least the first few and last few partitions.

`DELETEing` does not release space to the OS.

You need `innodb_file_per_table = ON` and `DROP PARTITION`, not `DELETE`.

If you ever use a "range" of days, partitioning by `DAYOFYEAR()` will perform poorly -- it will check all 52 partitions.

For efficient handling of a time series, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint